# Why i have Flutter gradle error on building project?

Tags: json, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, flutter, jcenter

when i building my flutter project i have the following error 
Launching lib/main.dart on Mi A2 in debug mode...

- Error running Gradle:

  Exit code 1 from: /home/khaled/flutter/oky/android/gradlew app:properties:
  Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  - Where:
    Build file '/home/khaled/flutter/oky/android/app/build.gradle' line: 25
  - What went wrong:

gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}


}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

  rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
  subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
  }
   subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
   }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: paste the error after - What went wrong:

Comment: i would suggest you to remove  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 } then run

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution? I also have this error!

Comment: @wagnerdelima i find the solution

Comment: Where is the solution @Khaledsb?

Comment: @wagnerdelima i changed the order of  jcenter() and maven in flutter/packages/flutter_touls/gradle/flutter.gradle

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution: It's still not in master branch but it's in beta. Master is the least stable version so far. Just do this in terminal:

```
flutter channel
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

and it should work